# Gnuplot 3D: x + y = const

Tags: gnuplot

How do I draw a vertical plane that is represented by:
`x + y = 1`

```
                        ^
                        |
                     1y | \
                        |   \
                        |     \ <-- this vertical plane
                        |       \
                        |         \
<-----------------------+----------------------->
              -1x       |         -1x
                        |
                        |
                        |
                    -1y |
                        |
                        v
```

Additionally I need to display multiple complex 3D equations (without `parametric`) at the same time.

Comment: Is it *on-topic* on stackoverflow?

Comment: @ikh Yes it is on-topic here. Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parametric` to plot your 3D equations like this:

```
f(x,y) = sin(x**2 + y**2)/(x**2 + y**2)
set parametric
splot u,v,f(u,v)
```

Together with the plane, a full script could look as follows:

```
set parametric

f(x,y) = sin(x**2 + y**2)/(x**2 + y**2)
const = 5
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set ticslevel 0
splot u,const-u,v title 'plane', u,v,f(u,v) title '3D equation'
```

For you real use case you might need to scale the `v` used as z-axis of the plane and maybe also the urange and vrange.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! I googled for hours to find a way to express normal 3D equations via `parametric`, your example was also the solution to this!